# SQL query giving error on join

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I want to run the below SQL query:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT (a.status_flag) counts, a.mkey, a.to_user
FROM  inward_doc_tracking_hdr a
  LEFT JOIN user_mst b ON a.to_user = b.mkey
WHERE a.to_user = 1260 AND a.status_flag = 4.
```

but it is not running, giving this error:

> Column 'inward_doc_tracking_hdr.Mkey' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

What is wrong here?

I am using SQL-server-2005.

**UPDATE**

I have an issue, when I run simple

```
select count(status_flag) from inward_doc_tracking_hdr where to_user = 1279
```

I get 2 count.

But when I run

```
SELECT COUNT (a.status_flag) counts, a.mkey, a.to_user, b.email, b.first_name + ' ' + b.last_name name FROM inward_doc_tracking_hdr a LEFT JOIN user_mst b ON a.to_user = b.mkey WHERE a.to_user = '1279' AND a.status_flag = '4' Group by a.mkey, a.to_user, b.email, b.first_name,b.last_name
```

and it shows me 2 rows.

why ?

Comment: You need a GROUP BY clause. Try adding `GROUP BY a.mkey, a.to_user` at the end of your statement,.

Comment: @jarlh: `groupby` where for whole query or a part of it ?

Comment: @jarlh: thanks, it worked.. I missed that :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you `select` list has combination of `aggregate` and `non aggregate` columns you need to add `Group by` with `non aggregate` columns

```
SELECT COUNT (a.status_flag) counts, a.mkey, a.to_user
FROM inward_doc_tracking_hdr a
  LEFT JOIN user_mst b ON a.to_user = b.mkey
WHERE a.to_user = 1260 AND a.status_flag = 4
Group by a.mkey, a.to_user
```

Comment: @NK - This Should be a new question

Answer (score 1):

In general, when you use a `LEFT JOIN` with aggregation, you want to count the number of matches in the *second* table, not the *first*.  So:

```
SELECT COUNT(b.mkey) as counts, a.mkey, a.to_user
FROM inward_doc_tracking_hdr a LEFT JOIN 
     user_mst b
     ON a.to_user = b.mkey
WHERE a.to_user = 1260 AND a.status_flag = 4
GROUP BY a.mkey, a.to_user;
```

Your version of the query (when fixed) would return a count of "1" even when no rows match in `b`.

Comment: look at my updated question. I want to get the count but it is not coming exactly the way i want

Answer (score 0):

You need to use group by on columns are not included in the count()

```
SELECT COUNT (a.status_flag) counts, a.mkey, a.to_user
FROM inward_doc_tracking_hdr a
  LEFT JOIN user_mst b ON a.to_user = b.mkey
WHERE a.to_user = 1260 AND a.status_flag = 4.
group by a.mkey, a.to_user
```